# How to have a configuration class, inject something already created by spring-boot and change it

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, activiti

I am trying to extend [activiti-spring-boot](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/master/modules/activiti-spring-boot) to integrate it with spring-security.

This is my first time with both spring and spring-boot. I get lots of great result researching for how to write code to do that. What interest me is this answer.

https://github.com/jbarrez/spring-boot-with-activiti-example/issues/5

Which I did post my own question at the end of that github issue.

What I want to ask here is that, conceptually what does it means by

"The regular Spring way: have a @Configuration class and inject the ProcessEngine or ProcessEngineConfiguration bean that is created by Spring Boot."

Does this means that Spring Boot already configure either of ProcessEngine or ProcessEngineConfiguration bean and somehow I can inject them and continue configuring them without loosing what already configured by Spring Boot?

Is this how dependency injection work? This is a conceptual question because I thought dependency injection is just a way to replace interface with implementation of that interface. And my understanding is that if, for instance I replace ProcessEngineConfiguration bean, I will lost all the configuration done by Spring-Boot and have to reconfigure them again.

Keep in mind that my understand of anything Spring is most probably wrong!

TIA

*To clarify: activiti-spring-boot is a getting started project that integrate activiti and spring using spring boot. It is using basic authentication. I want to use token base authentication so I actually try to integrate activit-spring-boot with spring security using another spring-boot stuff called spring-boot-starter-security.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the meaning of dependency injection. Dependency injection means that you've got what you need to get your class working injected. This concept usually relates to IoC (Control Inversion), which is to have a framework managing your control structure and injecting the dependencies. That's done by standard core Spring. Spring boot is a modern tool, which takes advantage of Spring in order to have some default configuration loaded (you tell boot what you need and give some configurable values and boot creates some ready-to-be-injected beans for you).

Comment: However, let say if I extend/inherit a class and inject it using the @Bean annotation to replace the parent/inherited class. Wouldn't this means that my  custom class and its code will be used instead of the parent class. How this can continue with the same configuration done by Spring Boot is still a big question which I am investigating now and will post here when I get a working solution. Thanks & Regards!

Comment: I don't really understand how this @ Bean can be used to inject a class that extend another class. But the code that I am writing now use @ Configuration and inside it I can use @Bean to create a function that return another class. This confuse me a lot since I thought beans is POJO. But in my current code, it is used to annotate function that return a class. The other confusing thing is that when I have several @ Bean annotating function. Not all of this function will be called (i.e. I set breakpoint and debug them). Spring is driving me mad since I can't trace code that is not executed :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential Answer from me

The code  so far can be seen [here](https://forums.activiti.org/content/even-after-customize-user-and-group-identityservice-still-create-user-actiduser-and-group). I have no idea how to put code here beside the pain in the ass of having to indent 4 spaces at every line.

So what I have done is extend a class and add the custom functionality into one of the overridden method in that class.

Then have a @Configuration class where the above class is injected using @Bean annotation instead of the parent class. I think this is the key to understanding

"The regular Spring way: have a @Configuration class and inject the ProcessEngine or ProcessEngineConfiguration bean that is created by Spring Boot."

Though what I did is not exactly the above. What I did can be summarize as

"Have a class that extend ProcessEngineFactoryBean and change one method to add custom user and group managers. And then in configuration class, use this class instead of ProcessEngineFactoryBean."

Since I did not reconfigure whatever has been configured by spring-boot. And merely change ProcessEngineFactoryBean with my own class that extend it. I did achieve what I need to achieve without disturbing/changing existing configuration.

With that said, while the code did what it need to do. It still does not work as expected. Hence the reason I post a question in Activiti forum.